# CSS layout change for print preview with angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, frontend

I have developed a single page angular app. I have a complex view where i need different formatting for page prints. There is a print button and when i clicked it, the layout should change to fit everything nicely. Using a different template is not an option because it takes like a minute or two to run some humongus query on the backend to fetch the data. (also it'd be neat not to have the page refreshed just for the print preview)

**Current Situation:**
When i clicked on the button i trigger a function to add a url parameter to the current url to check if i'm in the print preview mode so i can use the browser controls to go back to if i want to. `$location.search({ 'printPreview': 'True'});` also used `document.getElementById('print').style.display = 'none';` this focusing to hide the print preview button on the print view. NO LUCK! :(

**Workflow:** 
[image]

**I need help with:** Understanding the best approach to implement this by staying in the same page. any additional code help would be fantastic too. Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS.  No javascript needed.

```
.some-class {
    width: 40%;
}

@media print {
    .no-print {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .print-only {
        display: block !important;
    }

    .some-class { /* width and color got changed in print */
        width: 60%;
        color: #ff0 !important;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- will not show up on print -->
<div class="no-print">Click here to print</div>

<!-- will only show up on print -->
<div class="print-only">Page number 1/2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! but you'd need javascript to go back to the normal view right?

Comment: If you're talking about two different views/states, then yes, I suggest using [ui router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) using parent and child states.  `$stateProvider.state("main", {templateUrl: "main.html"}).state("main.print", {templateUrl: "print.html"});`  In this case, `main.print` is a child of `main`.  Doing this will allow you to use different templates, while sharing the same controllers.  It will help you achieve what you're trying to do with a lot more flexibility.

Comment: I am trying to print a table with 50 column but on print document template it displays only 20 columns rest of all are hidden. Could you please help me how to solve this issue and display entire table's column in single row?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the stylesheet in Angular pretty easily.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="{{ CurrentCSSFilename }}">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.CurrentCSSFilename = "web-view.css";
```

When the user clicks on the print button, it runs a function that changes the `CurrentCSSFilename` scope variable:

```
$scope.ClickPrint = function() {
    $scope.CurrentCSSFilename = "print-view.css";
}
```